# Default Values are not working in Select using react-hook-form

Tags: react-hook-form

I m using a react-hook-form form my form to submit the input and preload the data in form fields. I m using custom components for my select. I m using material UI, react-hook-form, nextjs.

CodeSandbox:-
https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-hooks-qtx7r?file=/components/Form.js